# Amazon MQ (Apache ActiveMQ) Event Source Lambda payload is missing Destination

Tags: aws-lambda, activemq-classic, amazon-mq

I have an AWS Lamda that is configured to receive messages from an Amazon MQ (Apache ActiveMQ) via an MQ trigger. I depend on the destination object shown in the [example MQ record event in the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-mq.html#services-mq-configure) to know from which queue the message is coming. However, in reality, the message object has an empty destination object, and I am unsure why.  The object looks good otherwise.

This is what the example looks like in the AWS documentation.

```
{
   "eventSource": "aws:mq",
   "eventSourceArn": "arn:aws:mq:us-west-2:111122223333:broker:test:b-9bcfa592-423a-4942-879d-eb284b418fc8",
   "messages": [
      { 
        "messageID": "ID:b-9bcfa592-423a-4942-879d-eb284b418fc8-1.mq.us-west-2.amazonaws.com-37557-1234520418293-4:1:1:1:1", 
        "messageType": "jms/text-message",
        "deliveryMode": 1,
        "replyTo": null,
        "type": null,
        "expiration": "60000",
        "priority": 1,
        "correlationId": "myJMSCoID",
        "redelivered": false,
        "destination": { 
          "physicalname": "testQueue" 
        },
        "data":"QUJDOkFBQUE=",
        "timestamp": 1598827811958,
        "brokerInTime": 1598827811958, 
        "brokerOutTime": 1598827811959 
      },
      { 
        "messageID": "ID:b-9bcfa592-423a-4942-879d-eb284b418fc8-1.mq.us-west-2.amazonaws.com-37557-1234520418293-4:1:1:1:1",
        "messageType": "jms/bytes-message",
        "deliveryMode": 1,
        "replyTo": null,
        "type": null,
        "expiration": "60000",
        "priority": 2,
        "correlationId": "myJMSCoID1",
        "redelivered": false,
        "destination": { 
          "physicalname": "testQueue" 
        },
        "data":"LQaGQ82S48k=",
        "timestamp": 1598827811958,
        "brokerInTime": 1598827811958, 
        "brokerOutTime": 1598827811959 
      }
   ]
}
```

This is what the event object looks like in reality as JSON when logged out.
[image]

This is the MQ Trigger.
[image]

This is what the object looks like in the Active MQ console.
[image]